# Sandbox account logging on to Paypal Overview page and not Confirmation page

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I have a payment form created within Jotform
https://form.jotformpro.com/71556656032962

I am using it to test a new payment option for our website. Once the payment option is selected and the user elects to "Subscribe Now" it directs to the PayPal Sandbox confirmation form for Login.

After logging in with a valid Test account in our Sandbox it then goes to the PayPal overview account screen rather than the confirmation of payment screen..

I am trying to workout what next steps I take to resolve this issue.
It was working a couple of weeks ago when I lasted tested this payment process. 
Has something changed in the use of PayPal Sandbox accounts ?

Answer (score 0):

We have a known issue at our end in the sandbox environment, which is causing this issue. Our engineering team is working on the fix. Will update once it fixes.